# Banco de dados - SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que necessita de um banco de dados, eu escolhi o SQLite.

Como sou novo e não tenho experiência em SQLite eu venho perguntar a vocês: Como eu posso criar um banco de dados com SQLite e React Native?

Answer (score 2):

Se você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando o *framework* [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) e deseja persistir dados usando SQLite diretamente, talvez, eu digo talvez, não seja tão interessante pois tem que explorar funcionalidades nativas dos dispositivos em suas determinadas plataformas. Caso sua aplicação seja híbrida, isso dificultará pois cada plataforma possui suas peculiaridades. Seria algo como [reinventar a roda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventar_a_roda), como muitos dizem. Mário Quintana diz que "*A preguiça é mãe do progresso. Se o homem não tivesse preguiça de caminhar, não teria inventado a roda*".

Mas existem alguns *plugins* de código aberto que permite que você manipule banco de dados SQLite usando JavaScript. Dê uma olhada nesses:

- https://github.com/almost/react-native-sqlite
- https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Caso queira refazer a roda de forma mais eficiente, você pode tomar como base estes mesmo *plugins* e melhora-los ou até mesmo refaze-los.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal dar uma olhada nessa página sobre a API de AsyncStorage? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Você pode usar a AsyncStorage para armazenar dados em pares de key-value. De acordo com a documentação, a implementação da API usa SQLite (ou RocksDB) se for Android.